# Android Tabs to be displayed one above the other in the screen

Tags: android, tabs, tabbar

Am new to android. I want my 3 tabs to be displayed at the bottom of the screen(one above the other).Please help me.

Comment: it's impossible with default action bar

Comment: what have you tried, and please be more specific. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. What do you want exactly? Are you referring to TabActivity?

Comment: Yes...am referring to a tab activity. I have 3 tab bars displayed at the bottom of the screen.Now I want my my tabs in vertical direction at the bottom. that means tab1 sits on tab2 and tab2 sits on tab3.And when I click on tab1 , an activity should be displayed and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this tutorial](http://kandroid.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/tabview-part-5-tab-control-at-bottom-of-app/).
It has some 7 to 8 parts and provides complete guideline about `TabView`.